# How to remove numpy array row which matches the string in list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have got an array which looks like

```
array = array([['Mango', 0.75, 0.25],
               ['Honey', 0.75, 0.25],
               ['Grape', 0.625, 0.375],
               ['Pineapple', 0.5, 0.5]], dtype=object)
```

and a list `item = {'Honey','Grape'}`
now, have to remove the rows from the array which matches the items in the list.

**Expected Output:**

```
array = array([['Mango', 0.75, 0.25],
               ['Pineapple', 0.5, 0.5]], dtype=object)
```

Have tried the below code but somehow it doesn't work.

```
array[:] = [x for x in array[:,0] if item not in x]
```

Help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = array[ ~np.isin(array[:, 0], item) ]
```

out:

```
array([['Mango', 0.75, 0.25],
       ['Pineapple', 0.5, 0.5]], dtype=object)
```

but you may want to have a look at a np.recarray or a pandas DataFrame, which is more suited to this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a[np.all(a[:,0][:, None] != itens, axis=1), :]
```

Output:

```
array([['Mango', 0.75, 0.25],
       ['Pineapple', 0.5, 0.5]], dtype=object)
```